# Programatically Added Widget not shown

Tags: python, kivy

A Programatically added Widget is not shown.

Dear Community, as I need to add some plain text I will elaborate
I try to add a widget to a FloatLayout in Kivy and I would expect it to show up
on top of the existing Label but it's not shown

What I'm doing wrong?

Python File:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_file('Test1.kv')

class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class RecScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Test1(App):

    def build(self):
        self.sm=ScreenManager()
        return self.sm

    def on_start(self):
        Layout = self.sm.ids['screen'].ids['fl_Rec']
        print(Layout)
        Layout.add_widget(Label(text='Hi!'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kivy.app import App

    Test1().run()
```

Test1.kv File:

```
<ScreenManager>:
    id:screen_manager
    Screen:
        id:screen

<Screen>:
    id:screen
    FloatLayout:
        id:fl_Rec
        Label:
            text:'Hello World'
```

THX

Martin

Following the hint of @furas I changed the .kv to

```
<ScreenManager>:
id:screen_manager
Screen:
    id:screen

<Screen>:
     id:screen
     FloatLayout:
        id:fl_Rec
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,1,1,0.1
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos:self.pos
        Label:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,0.5,1,0.1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos:self.pos
            size_hint: None,None
            size:50,20
            pos_hint: {'x':0.2,'y':0.2}
            text:'Hello World'
```

Still no luck !

Hi, is not lurking hidden somwhere!

Comment: when I run code the I see both text `Hello World` and `Hi!` in the same place. Tested on Linux Mint, Python 3.8, Kivy 2.0.0. But I think it is not good idea. Widget may have non-transparent background and hide other widget.

Comment: Thx, I was running On Win7 Python 3.7 Kivy 2.0.0

Comment: Not using Builder to load .kv shows expected behavior

Comment: it is strange behaviour. You could add this (with detaisl) as answer. And next you can mark your answer as accepted and upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem lies with using Builder to load the .kv File

I reported this behavior to

https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/7723

So let's hope somebody more knowledgeable will  resolve it.

Martin